# How to loop trough nested JSON and get value using Java, SpringBoot

Tags: java, json, spring-boot

I have a nested JSON that I want to loop through and get value based on key.

**Data.json**

```
{
  "car": [
    {
      "date": 1324599600000,
      "values": [
        {
          "name": "Audi",
          "price": "11212.12"
        },
        {
          "name": "Bmw",
          "price": "22321.3"
        },
        {
          "name": "Cittroen",
          "price": "23432.2"
        },
        {
          "name": "Tuareg",
          "price": "556456.3"
        }
      ]
    }
```

I created 3 object models based on JSON data.

**CarResponse.java**

```
public class CarResponse {

    @JsonProperty(value = "car")
    List<Car> cars;

    //getters,setters
```

**Car.java**

```
public class Car{

    @JsonProperty("values")
    private List<CarValue> carValue;  
    //getters, setters
```

**CarValue.java**

```
public class CarValue {
    private String name;
    private BigDecimal price;
    //getters, setters
```

**DataParse.java**

```
public class DataParse{
    
        CarResponse response;
    
        public CarValue parse(){
            CarValue carValue = new CarValue();
    
            //NEED HELP WITH THIS PART
            for(Car cars : response.getQuote()){
                for(CarValue qv : cars.getCarValue()){
                    String type = qv.get("name").asText();
                    Decimal value = qv.get("price").decimalValue();
    
                    carValue.setName(qv.getName());
                    carValue.setPrice(qv.getPrice());
                    
                }
            }
    
            return quoteValue;
        }
    }
```

In JSON I need to check if car name is Audi and if car name is Tuareg then save it and display it.

Nested for loop part of code is not working

```
for(Car cars : response.getQuote()){
                for(CarValue qv : cars.getCarValue()){
                    String type = qv.get("name").asText();
                    Decimal value = qv.get("price").decimalValue();
    
                    carValue.setName(qv.getName());
                    carValue.setPrice(qv.getPrice());
                    
                }
            }
```

Just put it as an example of what I need to do in this step which is check for key in JSON and if it is that key with for example `name = Audi` then

`carValue.setName(qv.getName());`

With my code above I am getting this in the console.

`carValue=[carValue{name=null, price=null}`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your deserialization is working correctly, you should change the part that "is not working" to:

```java
String type = qv.getName();
BigDecimal value = qv.getPrice();
```

If for some reason you want to use this qv.get(key) method, you should post its implementation.

When getName and getPrice are still returning null, it means you have a problem with the deserialization, for example a wrong setter method name. Still, without the implementation is impossible to understand.

Here is the [official documentation](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind) of Jackson, the library used by default with spring-boot for JSON serialization / deserialization.

And here is [Spring blog post](https://spring.io/blog/2014/12/02/latest-jackson-integration-improvements-in-spring) about it.

Comment: I just updated my question I have a problem with nested for loop and part that you have updated. In the first loop I try to iterate through `CarResponse` list to get `Car` because it contains `CarValues` that contain field `name` and `price`. But I guess I am doing something wrong because `cars.getCarValue()` in second loop is underlined red with error `foreach not applicable to type 'modal.CarValue'`

Comment: According to Car.java class,  the property with the name carValue has a type of List<CarValue>, but the error you are getting means that the method cars.getCarValue() returns a single object of type CarValue, and you can't loop over it, obviously, since it is not a List, hence the error.

Comment: So what can I do to get CarValue properties? @gere

Comment: Without look at your setter and getters, and how all the object instances are created, I can't really say.